# Can't Ping from LAN to WAN and port forwarding is KO

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, lan, home-networking, wan

hope you can help me out.

I have a modem (192.168.1.1) and a router (Xiaomi AX3600) connected to it via cable (192.168.1.2) which is creating a WAN (192.168.31.1).

All devices are connected to Xiaomi and so my webserver on a Raspberry (192.168.31.232).
I have a domain pointing to the raspberry, which was/is working fine when connected to the modem (it was 192.168.1.232).

On the modem I had all the ports forwarded, 80 and 443, did the same with the Xiaomi, but nothing works. 80/443 results closed from outside. Also tried with DMZ.

Also:
If I connect to the wifi from the modem (192.168.1.x), I can't ping any WAN (192.168.31.x) ip.
If I connect to the wifi of the WAN ip (192.168.31.x), I can ping any 192.168.1.x IP successfully.

I have no firewall, no upnp and I just did a reset on both devices. the only enabled setting on the modem is the loopback, and in the Xiaomi is the dmz on 31.232.

So it's like anything coming from outside my lan, gets "stuck in the modem" and don't go to any device connected to the Xiaomi.

Any suggestions? Please tell me I'm doing something stupid :)
Thanks!

Comment: right after posting this question, I managed to make it work, after struggling three whole days..! I have put from the modem in DMZ the IP of the Xiaomi and all ports finally worked. (I still can't ping from lan to wan but I believe this is more secure? :D )

Comment: This comment should be a separate answer, answers should not be edited into questions